# HTML5 game move sprite with button press

Tags: javascript, html, quintus

I have a basic game moving a sprite around a map using Quintus html5 game. I have the sprite moving from square to square (64px) with a keypress fine. I want the player to move one square also when a button is click on the webpage.

I am unsure how to call the `step` method in Quintus from a button click.

Outside the canvas I have a `<button id="move-player">Move Player One Square</button>`

```
document.getElementById("move-player").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
  //move player one square by possibly calling PlayerControls step 

});
```

Quintus player code

```
Q.component("PlayerControls", {
    // default properties to add onto our entity
    defaults: {speed: 32, direction: 'null'},

    // called when the component is added to
    // an entity
    added: function () {
        var p = this.entity.p;

        // adding default properties
        Q._defaults(p, this.defaults);

        // every time our entity steps, call its step method
        this.entity.on("step", this, "step");
    },

    step: function (dt) {
        // entity's properties
        var p = this.entity.p;

        var total_points = Q.state.get("points");
        if (total_points >= 4) {
            Q.state.set("points", 4);
            Q.stageScene("GameOverMsg", 2);//display game over message
        }//inner if

        // direction from the input will help in animation
        p.direction =   Q.inputs['left'] ? 'left' :
                        Q.inputs['right'] ? 'right' :
                        Q.inputs['up'] ? 'up' :
                        Q.inputs['down'] ? 'down' : null;


        window.onkeyup = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)//left
            {
                p.x -= p.speed;
                move_collision = "left";
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 38)//up
            {
                if (!(p.y <= 36)) {
                    p.y -= p.speed;
                    move_collision = "up";
                }
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 39)//right
            {
                p.x += p.speed;
                move_collision = "right";
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 40)//down
            {
                if (!(p.y >= 480)) {
                    p.y += p.speed;
                    move_collision = "down";
                }
            }
        };

        // movement
        switch (move_collision) {
            case "left":
                p.x -= p.speed;
                move_collision = "";
                break;
            case "right":
                p.x += p.speed;
                move_collision = "";
                break;
            case "up":
                p.y -= p.speed;
                move_collision = "";
                break;
            case "down":
                if (!(p.y >= 480)) {
                    p.y += p.speed;
                }
                move_collision = "";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
});

//Player Sprite
Q.Sprite.extend("Player",
    {
        init: function (properties) {
            properties.sheet = "snailspritesheet";
            properties.sprite = "snail";
            properties.frame = 4;
            this._super(properties);
            this.add("2d,PlayerControls,animation,tween");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that `step` function is a kind of callback function.
That function is called periodically with timer.

So, there are two method to move a player

> 1. Make a state machine: change state when button is clicked and interleave the code to `step` function for moving player
> 2. Make a trigger function to move a player with global variable: for example,

```
var player;
Q.scene("start",function(stage) {
    stage.insert(new Q.UI.Button({
        asset: 'move.png',
        x: Q.width/2,
        scale: 0.5,
        y: 370
     }, function() {
        player.x += 10;
        player.y -= 10;
     })
  );
}
```

I hope it is useful to you.